# haproxy will get 404 error for about 2-3 seconds if one of backend server down

Tags: http-status-code-404, backend, haproxy

this is the haproxy config.

```
defaults
  option forwardfor
  log global
  option httplog
  log 127.0.0.1 local3
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client  5000ms
  timeout server 5000ms

listen stats
    bind    *:9000
    mode    http
..............................................
backend testhosts
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
    server host1 11.11.11.11:9080  check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 2
    server host2 11.11.11.12:9080  check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 2
```

if service of 11.11.11.11 is down, haproxy will get 503 and 404 error about 2-3 seconds( it depends inter value, if inter value is very
small, the number of 404 error will be decreased).

2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    2274
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.22:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    448
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080    503 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    0
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080    404 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    0
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    1503
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    617
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.11:9080    404 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    0
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    618
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.11:9080    404 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    0
2020-08-25T11:58:16 host1 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "Not Found", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    645
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080    200 POST    /tsturl1    HTTP/1.1    618\

My question is :
why the parameter  retry  didn't work ? is it possible for the user always  get 200 code rather than 400 error even when one of the backend server down ？
I'm using Haproxy 1.5.18.

THanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the version you are using `retries` is for Layer 4 (i.e. connection timeout). HAProxy 2.0 introduced Layer 7 retries. These 2 blog posts may be helpful:

[HAProxy 2.0](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-2-0-and-beyond/#layer-7-retries)

[Layer 7 Retries and Chaos Engineering](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-layer-7-retries-and-chaos-engineering/)