# can haproxy ensure every call to backend server is successful when one of backend server is down?

Tags: backend, haproxy

haproxy config.

```
defaults
  option forwardfor
  log global
  option httplog
  log 127.0.0.1 local3
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client  5000ms
  timeout server 5000ms

listen stats
    bind    *:9000
    mode    http
..............................................
backend testhosts
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
    server host1 11.11.11.11:9080  check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 2
    server host2 11.11.11.12:9080  check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 2
```

if service of 11.11.11.11 is down, haproxy will get 503 and 404 error about 2-3 seconds( it depends inter value, if inter value is very small, the number of 404 error will be decreased).

```
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 2274
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 448
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 503 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 0
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 404 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 0
2020-08-25T11:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 1503
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 617
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.11:9080 404 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 0
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 618
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.11:9080 404 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 0
2020-08-25T11:58:16 host1 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "Not Found", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue. 2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 645
2020-08-25T11:58:16 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 618\
```

My question is : why the parameter retry didn't work ? can haproxy ensure every call to backend server is successful when one of backend server is down ? the version of  Haproxy 1.5.18. i also tried on 2.2.2, i got the same error.

Comment: i tried to add "   http-check disable-on-404" to haproxy.cfg and then restart haproxy, but it seems it didn't work.                                                                                                                 
      ''' 2020-08-28T16:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 2274
2020-08-28T16:58:14 11.11.11.22:9080 200 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 448
2020-08-28T16:58:14 11.11.11.11:9080 503 POST /tsturl1 HTTP/1.1 0

Answer (score 0):

You already asked this question in a separate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582064/haproxy-will-get-404-error-for-about-2-3-seconds-if-one-of-backend-server-down/63582469#63582469) and I provided you the resources that would answer your question. It seems that you did not read the resources that I provided nor did you award me points for answering your question.

As I mentioned before, you need to use HAProxy 2.0 and above. However, if you had read the blog posts that I supplied you would have found that you also need to use [retry-on](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-retry-on)

Comment: thanks you so much,  i just tried "retry-on " to none (also set retries to 3), i can just got 3 error records in the error during my test ( about 10 request per second for my test) . my question is : is possible for haproxy direct the failed call to the another avaiable backend server to ensure every request can get successful response even one of the backend server is down ?

Comment: You would use `option redispatch` to send requests to a different server within the backend

Comment: please see my  configuration, i did configure "option redispatch " in  default part, but there are still some error call record in my log file, should i configure "option redispatch" in backend part  rather in default part ?